# Mybatis - ExecutorType BATCH & autoCommit

Tags: java, mybatis

I use **mybatis** in a project.

1. When write the dao level, I am wondering what happens when set`ExecutorType` to `BATCH`, **does it just disable autoCommit**?
2. If yes, is it equal to call: `SqlSessionFactory.openSession(true);` ?